# How do I disable nuxt default error redirection

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Set up a nuxt project with Vuetify. One of the pages uses a `client-only` (`no-ssr`) component. During development, in case of an error in this component, I get redirected to the default error page, which prevents me from inspecting the variables and components using Vue devtools.

I feel like it should be really simple but I couldn't find a way to disable this auto redirecting behavior. So I guess my question is how do you disable nuxt default error redirection?

Comment: https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20200904-ErrorHandlingInNuxtjs.html

Comment: I dont know how to disable redirection for error layout, although I guess that many people dont want to disable it in production environment and they need this only for development purposes, I would suggest in the if condition to add this process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' in order to disable redirection only in dev env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable the `<nuxt-error>` rendering from the nuxt configuration.

Another way is to hack the nuxt render as follows:

1/ open the file `./node_modules/@nuxt/vue-app/template/components/nuxt.js`
2/ go to the `render(h)` method
3/ remove the error condition to always show the component:

```js
  render (h) {

    // HACK TO SKIP ERROR
    this.nuxt.err = false

    // if there is no error
    if (!this.nuxt.err) {
      // Directly return nuxt child
      return h('NuxtChild', {
        key: this.routerViewKey,
        props: this.$props
      })
    }

    // ...
  }
```

**nb:** after each *npm* or *yarn* install the hack in the file above will be overwrite.

Comment: Can't believe this is not customizable...

Answer (score 6):

I found a hack with a nuxt plugin :

./plugins/errors.js

```
export default function({ app }) {
  app.nuxt.error = () => {}
}
```

./nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    "~/plugins/errors.js",
  ],
}
```

Comment: Note this still uses the error layout, I can't find a way to disable that

Answer (score 1):

You can use global handler like this

```
Vue.config.errorHandler = (error) => {
   ErrorService.onError(error);
   return true
}
```

You can look into .nuxt/client.js
Block where they are defining Vue error handler.

```
const defaultErrorHandler = Vue.config.errorHandler
  Vue.config.errorHandler = async (err, vm, info, ...rest) => {
    // Call other handler if exist
    let handled = null
    if (typeof defaultErrorHandler === 'function') {
      handled = defaultErrorHandler(err, vm, info, ...rest)
    }
    if (handled === true) {
      return handled
    }

 ...some code to define layout
```